# Best design for spatial cost-minimizing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, spatial

I am working with a set *L* of land parcels and a set *C* of counties. Each parcel *L_i* costs *m* dollars and takes up *b* acres. Each county *C_i* requires *n* acres of parcels. Assume for now that the counties do not care about getting a bit more than *n* acres if the last parcel to be allocated to them "overfills" their capacity. Finally, *L_i* must be within *x* miles of the *C_i*'s centroid to be considered for allocation to *C_i*.

I designed an allocation algorithm to solve this problem such that *C_i* achieves *n* acres while minimizing cost *m*. However, the design is incredibly computationally intensive. Let *L_c* be the land parcels within *x* miles of *C_i*. My algorithm sorts *L_c* by cost in ascending order, allocates the first *n*-acres, then moves on to the next county.

Any ideas on how to make this more efficient? Are there established algorithms designed for such allocation problems?

Comment: Is it possible that a parcel is available for purchase by multiple counties? And if so, how many counties (on average) have an interest in any particular parcel?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Presumably there is a set of land parcels in each country that can be purchased by that country. If so, what is the importance of a land parcel being within a certain distance of a point in the country? Why don't you just limit consideration to properties in each country that satisfy that requirement? Having just seen @user3386109's comment, which reflects a different possible interpretation, I am even more confused. Please edit to clarify your question.

Comment: I've downvoted and voted to close. You were asked for clarification some time ago and have not responded. You are evidently aware of those requests as you selected an answer after they were made. You have a responsibility to make questions understandable, regardless of whether you are happy with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is extraordinarily difficult. Even without the "distance to centroid" restriction, the problem reduces to SUBSET-SUM which is NP-Complete (and adding the distance restriction does not change this). The short, informal proof is that if you wanted to solve an instance of SUBSET-SUM with some solution to this problem as an oracle, you could make it such that C_1 wants the target subset sum and C_2 wants the rest. That is to say, you won't find an efficient algorithm for solving this problem with perfect accuracy. That being said, you can get a *pretty good* algorithm that's *pretty fast*, sacrificing the accuracy of the solution to drastically speed it up.

The solution idea would be similar to yours, except you can use some BST to find unchosen parcels of land that are of maximal size but still don't overflow the C_i limit, until no additional parcel overfills C_i. Then, simply replace one of your chosen parcels with a slightly larger one such that you meet or exceed your quota (or just take another one, if it's easier). This will leave as many parcels of land available for other cities while still meeting C_i's quota. Then, continue to the next city.

You might be able to try and solve a better approximation for this with some form of integer simplex, but I wouldn't recommend going down that route. Sorry to give you the bad news, but you won't be finding any satisfyingly efficient algorithm that is 100% accurate anytime soon :(

Comment: Super helpful, thank you! How would one implement a BST in this situation?

Comment: Depends on the language. TreeSet in Java, Set in c++, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be formulated as a version of the assignment problem. As an experiment, I formulated a MIP (Mixed-Integer Programming) model for this with all random data.

It looks like:

```
 min sum(allowed(c,p),cost(p)*x(c,p)) 
 sum(allowed(c,p),x(c,p)) <= 1                 for all parcels p 
 sum(allowed(c,p),area(p)*x(c,p)) >= minacres  for all counties c
 x(c,p) ∈ {0,1}
```

Notes:

- c : counties
- p : plots
- allowed(c,p) are the allowed assignments (i.e. within distance)
- x(c,p) are binary decision variables (assignment)

With 100 counties and 1000 parcels it is difficult to find proven optimal solutions. But if we can stop a bit earlier on reaching a gap (difference between best found and best possible solution), then:

```
 5% gap reached after 1   seconds
 4%                   1.5
 3%                   6
 2%                   275
```